# unexpected maximum possible values for terra::writeRaster according to datatype

Tags: raster, terra

When using `terra::writeRaster`, the maximum possible values allowed for writing depend on the datatype (`INT1U`, `INT2S`, `INT2U`...).

The documentation tells that "When writing integer values the lowest available value (given the datatype) is used [to store `NA`, I suppose] for signed types, and the highest value is used for unsigned values.". This should give the following range for unsigned types:

`INT1U` : 0-254 (2^8-1, minus one for `NA` storage)

`INT2U` : 0-65,534 (2^16-1, minus one for `NA` storage)

`INT4U` : 0-4,294,967,294 (2^32-1, minus one for `NA` storage)

However, for unsigned datatypes `INT2U` and `INT4U`, the maxima I observed on my machine do not fit these expectations:

`INT2U` : 65,532
`INT4U` : 4,294,967,292

Why this unexpected maximum values? I ask the question because it is not insignificant, for safe code writing, to exactly know these maximum values before writing files.

I am working under Windows 10. Here is a couple of code lines that I used to check:

```
library(terra)
terra version 1.3.4
Warning message:
package ‘terra’ was built under R version 4.0.5 

r <- rast(ncols=1, nrows=2)
values(r) <- c(65532,65533)

writeRaster(r,"test.tif",wopt=list(datatype="INT2U"))

t <- rast("test.tif")
values(t)
     lyr.1
[1,] 65532
[2,]   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

With the development version I now get the expected result

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncols=1, nrows=4)
values(r) <- 65533:65536
```

2-byte unsigned integer

```
x <- writeRaster(r,"test.tif", datatype="INT2U", overwrite=TRUE)
values(x)
#     lyr.1
#[1,] 65533
#[2,] 65534
#[3,]   NaN
#[4,]   NaN

x <- writeRaster(r,"test.tif", datatype="INT2U", NAflag=0, overwrite=TRUE)
values(x)
#[1,] 65533
#[2,] 65534
#[3,] 65535
#[4,]   NaN
```

4-byte unsigned integer

```
values(r) <- 4294967293:4294967296
x <- writeRaster(r,"test.tif", datatype="INT4U", overwrite=TRUE)
values(x)
#          lyr.1
#[1,] 4294967293
#[2,] 4294967294
#[3,]        NaN
#[4,]        NaN


x <- writeRaster(r,"test.tif", datatype="INT4U", NAflag=0, overwrite=TRUE,)
values(x)
#          lyr.1
#[1,] 4294967293
#[2,] 4294967294
#[3,] 4294967295
#[4,]        NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly. terra is evolving so fast that the development version is a must!